# Difference between Centos CD and DVD versions

Tags: linux, iso-image, centos-5

What is the difference between Centos 5.8 CD and DVD versions?

I want to download Centos ISO files but stumbled upon two different files. One is of around 600MB and another is of massive 4GB.

Comment: The dvd has more on it, if it is like Ubuntu or Debian then you can install the rest direct from an internet repository on a package by package repository. The default install may be identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DVD gives you "more stuff", such as all the source code packages that go with the binary packages. You don't really need that. So just install from the smaller one. You get additional software and updates over the Internet later, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the two files go together. Part of a DVD disk set for [CentOS 5.8](http://centos.mbni.med.umich.edu/mirror/5.8/isos/x86_64/):

1. Disk 1 of 2: [CentOS-5.8-x86_64-bin-DVD-1of2.iso](http://centos.mbni.med.umich.edu/mirror/5.8/isos/x86_64/CentOS-5.8-x86_64-bin-DVD-1of2.iso) 4.3 GB
2. Disk 2 of 2: [CentOS-5.8-x86_64-bin-DVD-2of2.iso](http://centos.mbni.med.umich.edu/mirror/5.8/isos/x86_64/CentOS-5.8-x86_64-bin-DVD-2of2.iso) 640 MB